# Deleting a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

This is my first time working with pointers and I've been having some issues with deleting the dynamically allocated arrays that I've made with the `new` keyword. For this project that I'm working on, I am required to make every array a dynamic array.

I have 3 dynamic arrays and a pointer for each, but whenever I go to delete them, the third deletion causes my program to crash. To the best of my knowledge, I have used `delete[] ptr;` to delete each array after using them and my pointers are all pointing to the first element in the arrays at the time of deletion.

Here are all the instances where I use the third pointer in my program:

```
void compareAnswers (ifstream& responses, ifstream& answers)
{
/* Creating pointers and filling dynamic arrays with data */

//compare answers to responses
int totalMissed = 0;
int *ptr3 = new int[totalMissed];     //make a new dynamic array for missed questions
for (int i = 0; i <= totalQuestions - 1; i++)
{
    if (*(ptr1 + i) != *(ptr2 + i))       //if an answer is wrong...
    {
        totalMissed++;               // add to the total missed questions
        *ptr3 = i + 1;               // assign the missed question to the current spot in the array
        ptr3++;                      // increment the pointer
    }
}
ptr3 = ptr3 - totalMissed;      //returns ptr3 to position of first element in array

//display contestant's report
displayContestantsReport (contestantID, ptr3, totalMissed, totalQuestions, ptr1, ptr2);

//delete the dynamic arrays
delete[] ptr1;
ptr1 = nullptr;
delete[] ptr2;
ptr2 = nullptr;
delete[] ptr3;
ptr3 = nullptr;
}
```

Here is the displayContestantsReport function:

```
void displayContestantsReport (string ID, int *ptr3, int totalMissed, int totalQuestions, char *ptr1, char *ptr2)
{
    //display ID and score
    double score = (((static_cast<double>(totalQuestions)) - (static_cast<double>(totalMissed)))/static_cast<double>(totalQuestions)) * 100;
    cout << ID << " - " << fixed << setprecision(2) << score << endl;
//display missed questions
if (score != 100)
{
    //display question number
    for (int i = 0; i <= totalMissed - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == totalMissed - 1)
            cout << *(ptr3 + i) << endl;
        else
            cout << *(ptr3 + i) << " ";
    }

    //display contestant's responses
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= totalMissed - 1; i++)
    {
        //if question number is a single digit
        temp = *(ptr3 + i);
        if (temp >= 1 && temp <= 9)
        {
            if (i == totalMissed - 1)
                cout << *(ptr2 + (temp - 1)) << endl;
            else
                cout << *(ptr2 + (temp - 1)) << " ";
        }
        else //if question is a two digit letter
        {
            if (i == totalMissed - 1)
                cout << " " << *(ptr2 + (temp - 1)) << endl;
            else
                cout << " " << *(ptr2 + (temp - 1)) << " ";
        }
    }

    //display correct answers
    int temp2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= totalMissed - 1; i++)
    {
        //if question number is a single digit
        temp2 = *(ptr3 + i);
        if (temp2 >= 1 && temp2 <= 9)
        {
           temp2 -= 1;
            if (i == totalMissed - 1)
                cout << *(ptr1 + temp2) << endl;
            else
                cout << *(ptr1 + temp2) << " ";
        }
        else //if question is a two digit letter
        {
           temp2 -= 1;
            if (i == totalMissed - 1)
                cout << " " << *(ptr1 + temp2) << endl;
            else
                cout << " " << *(ptr1 + temp2) << " ";
        }
    }
}
cout << endl;
}
```

I am confused on where I messed up in the code and can provide any clarification where needed. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: `new int[N]` is not a dynamic array but *dynamically allocated* fixed-size array. Dereferencing the pointer returned from `new int[0];` is UB. Use `std::vector` if you need a dynamic one.

Comment: `int *ptr3 = new int[totalMissed];` should be `int *ptr3 = new int[totalQuestions];`, and `for (int i = 0; i <= totalQuestions - 1; i++)` (and similar loops) should be `for (int i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++)`.

Comment: Oh, I see now! So the issue was me setting the dynamically allocated array to a size of 0 initially? Does it matter that the size is being changed by the for loop right underneath it?

Comment: Yes, adding anything to storage of zero size leads to bad things happening -- quickly `:)` Remember, at its basics, a pointer is simply a normal variables that holds the address to something else as its value.

Comment: If you want to use a container whose size dynamically grows as you add elements to it, I suggest you read up on the [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)